# Setting environment variable before running published application in citrix

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I have a published application in my citrix server that flexes based on an environment variable which needs to be set in the server, after the session starts. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use .vbs script to set environment variable and then launch an application.

For example:

```
set ws = wscript.createobject("WScript.shell")
set systemEnv = wshShell.Environment("SYSTEM")
systemEnv("YourVariable") = "Your value"
ws.run("notepad.exe"), 0, true
```

Flags:

```
0 = Hidden
1 = displayed
True = Waits till command has completed before moving to next
False = Does not wait for command to complete before moving to next
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, I was trying to run it using a batch file. I was able to publish the batch file, but i was getting an error while trying to download the ica for the batch file. This is easier!